# Как собрать новый объект из свойств объектов лежащих в массиве?

Tags: javascript, json, парсер, объекты

У меня есть JSON файл в котором массив с объективами.

http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/ (первый файл)

Мне нужно из этого массива выбрать свойства id у каждого объекта и записать его в отдельный массив для дальнейшей работы. (идеальным будет просто файлик с массивом id-шек)

Вот как это пытался сделать я. Делалось это в консоли браузера сам массив (ids) был вставлен в html.

```
function ids1 (let i = 0; i < 209579; i++) {
    function (i) {
        ids.forEach(function(obj) {console.log(ids[i].id)})
    }
   }
```

Comment: На будущее, лучше в вопросе привести кусочек того джейсона. По ссылкам ходить не хочется никому. В ответе ниже я привёл, думаю, наглядный пример.

Comment: Лиза Журина, почему вы в тексте пишете о себе в мужском роде? Неувязочка ..

Comment: @Kromster почему неувязачка, а вдруг ТС - себя так ощущает?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const src = [
  {id: 1, data: 'data'},
  {id: 2, data: 'data'},
  {id: 3, data: 'data'},
  {id: 4, data: 'data'},
];

let dest = src.map(item => item.id);

console.log(dest);
```